# What is the dependence of weighted set cover problem on the sets/data given as input? Relevant research areas?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization

Let's say I'm given two set cover problems 1 and 2.  In both problems I'm required to cover the same universe $U$.  For each of the set cover problems, I have sets $S_{1,i}.....S_{1,n}$ and $S_{2,j}.....S_{2,m}$ with corresponding weights.  Assume both are well-posed.  I want to know how their optimal values compare, and their dependence on the input data.

Has there been research done regarding the dependence of the set cover problem on the sets $S$?  (data dependence).  What keywords to search that might be relevant for this?

Comment: In some sense, the universe $U$ doesn't matter. It is just how the sets interact that matters. (For instance, you could duplicate every element in $U$ a hundred times, and assign all copies of an element to the sets the original was, this would give an equivalent instance).